# Google GMail Api sends an email but drops some html

Tags: php, google-api, gmail-api

Hi I'm sending an email via google GMail API in PHP like this:

```
$strRawMessage = "From: Name <good@email.com>\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= "To: Another Name <anothergood@email.com>\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= 'Subject: =?utf-8?B?' . base64_encode('Subject') . "?=\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable' . "\r\n\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= 'Content<img src="http://example.com/img.jpg">';
$strRawMessage .= "\r\n";

$mime = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($strRawMessage), '+/', '-_'), '=');

$msg = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message;
$msg->setRaw($mime);
$response = $service->users_messages->send($userId, $msg);
```

And it works. Mail is in sended folder and recipient get's an email. However I found that in headers there are some wired things like:

```
Received: from 610088504391 named unknown by gmailapi.google.com with HTTPREST; Wed, 15 Feb 2017 12:17:37 -0800
```

or

```
Received: from mx.example.com (unresolved [10.174.34.83]:35438)
by ps8 (Ota) with LMTP id 1C2A929C5BB61
```

But I never used mx.example.com and I don't know 10.174.34.83 ip address...

GMail change my `<img src=...>` tag into `<img>` so it breaks the code. Any idea why this might happend?

Comment: The problem is that Google blocks external images by default.